# Optimization for an SSD?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, lvm, ext4, ssd

I am running Fedora 20 on a Laptop ( [Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 2 Pro](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/yoga/yoga-2-pro/#techspecs) ) with an SSD. My filesystem is LVM with ext4 as the format option. I am now running Fedora as the only OS on the system with Legacy BIOS turned on (the system came configured with Secure Boot) and with the entire hard drive reformatted for Fedora.

What optimizations should I institute to ensure long, and trouble free, SSD life?